# DRF Response content-type set to None during tests

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I'm using Django Rest Framework (version 3.6.2) to create REST API. I've defined my viewset that inherits from `GenericViewSet` and have overriden `retrieve` method to implement custom behaviour.

```
class FooViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ... 
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I want to have BrowsableAPI while accessing this endpoint from the browser and receive `json` response when accessing this endpoint e.g. from the code. I've configured DRF with the following settings:

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    ),
    'TEST_REQUEST_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'TEST_REQUEST_DEFAULT_FORMAT':'json'
}
```

Everything works as expected, I can access the browsable API from the browser and when making request with the Postman tool I get json response. Unfortunately, I can't achieve the same result during tests.

```
class GetFooDetailViewTest(APITestCase):

    def test_get_should_return_json(self):
        response = self.client.get(self.VIEW_URL)
        self.assertEqual(response.content_type, "application/json")
```

I expect the response to have content_type set to `application/json` (this is the header that I can see in the responses from browser and Postman). But this test fails - `response.content_type` is set to `None`. While debugging this test, I've discovered that `response._headers` dictionary looks like this

```
{
    'vary': ('Vary', 'Cookie'),
    'x-frame-options': ('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN'),
    'content-type': ('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
    'allow': ('Allow', 'GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
}
```

So it seems like the correct header is being set, but it's not getting populated to the `content_type` attribute. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I test for the content type.  In very few cases my code decides the content-type itself, so I to check that I *personally* did not do something wrong. DRF code is already tested.

```
self.assertEqual("application/json", resp['Content-Type'])
```

You just have to rely on DRF doing it right, its not something you can or need to test.  For example, you don't test that DRF parsed your json body correctly.  The test server isn't exactly like the real one, but its pretty close.  For example, you will get *real* objects out of response.data, not the json encoded/decoded ones.

Check out the [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase) if you need it, but it will be slower.

Comment: It works, but remember you are just retesting already tested code.  The content type in the response object will be correctly converted to text later.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, thanks. I think that it's really simple test and can detect unwanted/unintentional config changes in the future, so imho there is nothing bad about including this in my test suite. What do you think?

Comment: It can't hurt and would protect from breaking your own project settings :)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar and this worked for me:

`response = self.client.get(self.VIEW_URL, HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json')`